# .NET c# Serialize to Parm Name and value

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have the following object:

```
public class sampleObj
{
    public string MemberId {get;set;}
    public string Address {get;set;}
}
```

And the service I am talking to expects Property Names to be defined in a name attribute on a `<Parm/>` element, with its value within a child `' Xml element like so:

```
<Parm Name="SampleObj">
  <Parm Name="MemberId">
    <Value>1234</Value>
  </Parm>
  <Parm Name="Address">
    <Value>xyz</Value>
  </Parm>
</Parm>
```

When I serialize the sampleObj to XML, I get the following incorrect XML:

```
<sampleObj>
  <MemberId>1234</MemberId>
  <Address>xyz</Address>
</sampleObj>
```

How do I serialize my object as required?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use Linq2Xml (I find it more easy to use most of the time)

```
var root = new XElement("Parm",
                new XAttribute("Name", "SampleObj"),
                new XElement("Parm",
                    new XAttribute("Name", "MemberId"),
                    new XElement("Value", "1234")
                ),
                new XElement("Parm",
                    new XAttribute("Name", "Address"),
                    new XElement("Value", "xyz")
                )
            );

var output = root.ToString();
```

**Output:**

```
<Parm Name="SampleObj">
  <Parm Name="MemberId">
    <Value>1234</Value>
  </Parm>
  <Parm Name="Address">
    <Value>xyz</Value>
  </Parm>
</Parm>
```

Comment: It is not just these two properties of the class. The class might have more properties. Looking for a more generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
/// <summary>
/// When serialized, sampleObj is 'Parm' element
/// </summary>
[XmlRoot("Parm")]
public class sampleObj
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Name is an attribute of sampleObj/Parm
    /// </summary>
    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Value is an element of sampleObj/Parm
    /// </summary>
    [XmlElement("Value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// sampleObj has sampleObj list as elements
    /// </summary>
    [XmlElement("Parm")]
    public List<sampleObj> sampleObjs { get; set; }
}
```

Produces the result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Parm Name="sampleObj">
  <Parm Name="MemberId">
    <Value>1234</Value>
  </Parm>
  <Parm Name="Address">
    <Value>xyz</Value>
  </Parm>
</Parm>
```

Note:

There are additional steps (using the XmlSerializer class) to remove the instruction, if necessary.

Comment: Travis, how about  posting a working code besides that instructions how to do it? Question is specific enough for that...

Comment: How the property Name being passed as the attribute(Name) value?. I am actually stuck up at that serialization,I was able to define it, but while serializing I have the issue.  Every object need to be serialized to <Parm name="PropertyName"><value>propertyvalue</value></parm>

Comment: Setting the property Name value to 'sampleObj' on the top level object will produce the results I provided. The default behavior of the XmlSerializer, which I only assume you are using, is to serialize only the properties with set values.